# Sign Up page button doesn't respond when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a simple sign up page in an html file, but the sign up button is not responding.

I've tried to check if the if statement is considering the else statement as part of the setInterval, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
<h3>Sign Up</h3>
<input id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username"> <br>
<input id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password"> <br>
<button id="signButton" onclick="signUp()">Sign Up</button>
<p id="signupmessage"></p>
```

```
var buttonClicks = 0;
function signUp() {
    buttonClicks++;
    if (buttonClicks==5) {
        document.getElementById("signButton").disabled = true;
        var timeLeft = 10;
        var countdown = setInterval(){
            document.getElementById("signupmessage").innerHTML = "Sorry! You've hit the sign up button too many times. Please try again in " + countdown + ".";
            timeleft = timeLeft - 1;
            if (timeLeft <=0) {
                clearInterval(countdown);
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else {

    var username = document.getElementById("usernameInput").value
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordInput").value
    document.getElementById("signupmessage").innerHTML = username + " you've signed up with the password " + password +"!"
    }
```

I hoped this code would show a person that they signed up (haven't actually coded an account thing) but if they hit the button 5 times, it would disable the Sign Up button and create a countdown to when it would be reenabled. Instead the button simply doesn't work.

Comment: Is that the full js you are using for that `signup()` function? Because it has errors as it is now. Also that whole `var countdown = setInterval() {...}, 1000);` call doesn't seem right. Try `var countdown = setInterval(function() {...}, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

The way you have defined setInterval is invalid. Here is the corrected function.

```js
var buttonClicks = 0;
    function signUp() {
        buttonClicks++;
        if (buttonClicks==5) {
            document.getElementById("signButton").disabled = true;
            var timeLeft = 10;
            var countdown = setInterval(()=>{
                document.getElementById("signupmessage").innerHTML = "Sorry! You've hit the sign up button too many times. Please try again in " + countdown + ".";
                timeleft = timeLeft - 1;
                if (timeLeft <=0) {
                    clearInterval(countdown);
                }
            }, 1000);
        } else {

        var username = document.getElementById("usernameInput").value
        var password = document.getElementById("passwordInput").value
        document.getElementById("signupmessage").innerHTML = username + " you've signed up with the password " + password +"!"
        }}
```

```html
<h3>Sign Up</h3>
<input id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username"> <br>
<input id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password"> <br>
<button id="signButton" onclick="signUp()">Sign Up</button>
<p id="signupmessage"></p>
```

Comment: The countdown starts at 1 or 2, and is frozen. But I mean, it's a response!